# PHP: print sub category item group by mother catergory

Tags: php, html, css

I must to create a menù that contain a list of subcategory items group by mother category and take these values from product table:

**Category**

SubCategory

SubCategory

**Category**

SubCategory

I got this:

```
<?php
 $query_cat = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY category ORDER BY category");
 $query_cat->execute();

 print '<li><strong>'. $category . '</strong></li>'; //Category

 while ($cat_row = $query_cat->fetch()) {  //Subcategory
       print '<li><a href="/category/'. $cat_row['4'] .'">'. $cat_row['4'] .'</a></li>'; 
 }
 ?>
```

The `products` table structure is

`ID, name, stars, brand, category, priceavg, first-category`

How i can get the category name and put in top of the element?

Thanks to all for the help provided.

Comment: which is the structure of your `products` table ?

Comment: @Diego Mariani, sei italiano?

Comment: si, qual'è l struttura della tabella ?

Comment: Benissimo, dunque, la tabella è composta da ID, name, stars, brand, category, priceavg, first-category

Comment: super category = category   and   
sub category = first-category   ???

Comment: Normally, if you use category and subcategory, exist a table Category and a category has category father(referenced to other category) if is a subcategory.

Comment: @Cuchu sorry for the missing explaination: super category = first-category, sub-category = category

Comment: you may use GROUP_CONCAT for getting the subcategory as a single string, and then explode them for viewing the as subcategory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_group_by](https://github.com/jakezatecky/array_group_by) function as below

```
$query_cat = $db->prepare("SELECT name, category, first_category FROM products ORDER BY category");
$query_cat->execute();

$rows = $query_cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$items = array_group_by($rows, 'first_category');

foreach($items as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li><strong>' . $key . '</strong></li>';
    foreach($value as $row) {
        echo '<li><a href="/category/'.$row['category'].'">'.$row['category'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

The `array_group_by` is a function that groups an array by a key or set of keys shared between all array members.
Once you've retrieved your SQL data as an associative array, you can apply the `array_group_by` function an obtain an array of array such as categories and subcategories.

After the `array_group_by` this is a sample result of how your `$items` array is structured https://3v4l.org/5WkDH

Final live example here https://3v4l.org/cg9NN

**Tip** [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) Consider to not use `SELECT * FROM` in your queries

**EDIT** If you want compatibility to **PHP lower than 5.3**, you just have to change `[]` with `array()` short array notation. Live example here https://3v4l.org/0VUn7 *(tested from PHP 4.3 to latest)*

Comment: grazie, fetch_assoc() dovrebbe essere fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); giusto? Ottengo errore fatale Call to undefined function array_group_by()

Comment: yes, you must retrieve SQL results as associative array

Comment: the `array_group_by` function must be added as a library. Look at https://github.com/jakezatecky/array_group_by

Comment: I didn't know if you were using `mysqli` or `PDO`. I edited the `fetch_assoc`in order to get it right for PDO

Comment: I got Warning: Illegal string offset 'category' in /lib/array_group_by.php on line 24, instead the list got only initial letter of the array and some numbers where print surely related to the other table content

Comment: Nothing, i got Warning: Illegal string offset 'first_category' ... 1
Warning: Illegal string offset 'category' ... I ... 0 ... A ... etc

Comment: Your code won't work on PHP 5.3 and lower, which might be the version that is used by the O.P.. Sometimes, updating version is impossible (legacy code, for example). All you have to do is change every single time you create an array to use `array()` instead. Which is like .... 2...

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 and plan to use this version in production. can you explain more about change every single time?

Comment: Working using fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) instead of fetch(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: @andreaem This answer assumes you use PHP 5.4 or newer. The provided function breaks on PHP 5.3 and lower, due to a change in the syntax to create an array. Using the old syntax, will work in PHP 4 and up.